# How to maintain the insert and delete according to persist the entitymanager without commiting the whole trancation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How to maintain the delete and insert in the jpa and also how to keep duplicate data in the same entitymanager in jta and jpa

the execution of query is like this

```
delete from SERVERVARIABLES where SERVER_ID=? and VARIABLE_NAME=?

delete from SERVERVARIABLES where SERVER_ID=? and VARIABLE_NAME=?

insert into SERVERVARIABLES (DEFAULT_VALUE, description, SERVER_ID, VARIABLE_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

insert into SERVERVARIABLES (DEFAULT_VALUE, description, SERVER_ID, VARIABLE_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

i need the execution should be like

```
delete from SERVERVARIABLES where SERVER_ID=? and VARIABLE_NAME=?

insert into SERVERVARIABLES (DEFAULT_VALUE, description, SERVER_ID, VARIABLE_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

delete from SERVERVARIABLES where SERVER_ID=? and VARIABLE_NAME=?

insert into SERVERVARIABLES (DEFAULT_VALUE, description, SERVER_ID, VARIABLE_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

public void deleteservervariable(String serverId,String name) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = null;
    EntityManager entitymanager = null;
    try {
        entitymanager = JPAUtility.getInstance().getEntityManager 
                    (APIArtifactConstant.APIManagerCacheUnit);
        builder = entitymanager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaDelete<Servervariable> apidelete = builder.createCriteriaDelete(Servervariable.class);
        Root<Servervariable> apiserverVariabel = apidelete.from(Servervariable.class);
        apidelete.where(builder.equal(apiserverVariabel. 
                    get(APIArtifactImportConstant.id). 
                    get(APIArtifactImportConstant.apiserverId), 
                   serverId),builder.equal(apiserverVariabel. 
                     get(APIArtifactImportConstant.id). 
                   get(APIArtifactImportConstant.APIvariableName), name));
        entitymanager.joinTransaction();
        entitymanager.createQuery(apidelete).executeUpdate();
    }


    public void deleteservervariable(String serverId,String name)


    public void presistservervariable(Servervariable servervariable,EntityManager entitymanager) { 

        try { entitymanager.joinTransaction(); 
            entitymanager.persist(servervariable); } catch(Exception e) { 
   e.printStackTrace(); } }
```

Comment: Why is the the order of the statements important?

Comment: Because sometime the data may get repeated in insert query so i need to maintain the order and also it display error" a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: No JTA transcation, and JPA  @SimonMartinelli

Comment: And why don't you inject the EntityManager and have Spring take care of the transaction? However. You can call flush() to force execution of the SQL statements and to not rely on the order that Hibernate produces

Comment: But even while I am  using flush this error comes in console "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" and also whether I can use flush without using clear() in entitymanager to resolve this error  @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Do you have some idea about this @SimonMartinelli

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">


 <persistence-unit name="APIManagerCacheUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/Olive/OFDS</jta-data-source>
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apidoc</class>
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apidocinfo</class>

Comment: <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apioperation</class>
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.ApioperationPK</class>  
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apiparam</class>
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apiparamdtl</class>
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.ApiparamdtlPK</class>  
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apirep</class>
  <class>com.intellect.olive.apimanager.jpaentity.Apireqtemplate</class>

Comment: <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>

</persistence>

Comment: do you have any idea for this@James